# Struts 2 map type conversion

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2, type-conversion

In my jsp I have the a textfield: `<s:textfield name="codePropertyMap[%{#codeProperty.id}]" />` where the codePropertyMap is a `Map<CodeProperty, String>` in my action.

Now, I want to convert the `codeProperty.id` to a concrete `CodeProperty`, to do that I created a `CodeAction-conversion.properties` file with the following text:

```
KeyProperty_codePropertyMap=id 
Element_codePropertyMap=java.lang.String 
Key_codePropertyMap=CodePropertyImpl
```

But only with this is not working.

And in this page there is an example for list conversion
[Struts Type Conversion](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/type-conversion.html) but I can't see how it works with maps.

What I want to know is what I am missing or its not possible to do the conversion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you meant "conversion", NOT "conversation".  Don't forget to make sure your `CodeAction-conversion.properties` is named properly.

Comment: The name of the file was right. My mistake writing the question. And also the file is in the right folder. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I was trying to do it, I think, is not possible. The way I solved was to create a class that extends StrutsTypeConverter, that do the conversion. For more details about this problem and possible solution you can go were http://www.mail-archive.com/user%40struts.apache.org/msg102474.html