# What is the correct request parameter for map proprerty inside an object in Struts Action?

Tags: java, spring, request, struts2, struts2-interceptors

Consider the following `AnswerAction`:

```
public class AnswerAction extends CommonAction implements SessionAware {

    private CaseNumbering caseNumbering;
    (...)
}
```

And `FormCaseNumbering`

```
public class FormCaseNumbering implements CaseNumbering {

private Duplicable innermostElement;
Map<Duplicable, Integer> caseNumbersOfDuplicableFormElements = new HashMap<>();
(...)
}
```

and `DuplicableFormElement`

```
public class DuplicableFormElement implements Duplicable {

protected int id;
protected boolean duplicable;
}
```

In a Struts2 application where beans are injected via spring:

```
<bean id="caseNumbering" scope="prototype"
    class="model.FormCaseNumbering">
    <property name="innermostElement" ref="duplicableFormElement"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="answerAction" class="actions.AnswerAction" scope="prototype" autowire="byName">
    <property name="caseNumbering" ref="caseNumbering"/>
</bean>
```

**Question:**

How can you send a request parameter that populates the action with a caseNumbering containing a Map element with key `duplicableElement.id=6` and value `Integer=1` ?

**My attempts:**

Since the `caseNumbering` element is being injected via spring, I have no problem populating `innermostElement` , eg this works:

```
(MockHttpServletRequest)request.setParameter("caseNumbering.innermostElement.id","9");
```

However the following:

```
(MockHttpServletRequest)request.setParameter("caseNumbering.caseNumbersOfDuplicableFormElements[6]","1");
```

will fail with:

> Invalid field value for field "caseNumbering.caseNumbersOfDuplicableFormElements[6]".

I have also tried adding an AnswerAction-conversion.properties with the following, with no luck:

```
Key_caseNumbering.caseNumbersOfDuplicableFormElements=model.DuplicableFormElement
KeyProperty_caseNumbering.caseNumbersOfDuplicableFormElements=id
Element_caseNumbering.caseNumbersOfDuplicableFormElements=java.lang.Integer
CreateIfNull_caseNumbering.caseNumbersOfDuplicableFormElements=true
```

Is this possible in Struts2 (without needing to create a custom converter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a similar question: [Struts 2 map type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511771/struts-2-map-type-conversion)

And the answer, which can be [found in struts2' mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@struts.apache.org/msg102477.html), is still valid.

In short - there is a limitation in struts2 to handle this type of map and a custom converter is needed.

Comment: It's not a *similar* question, it's a link to *this* question?

Comment: hah, thanks for pointing it out - a case of wrong copy-pasting. fixed!